# Recover detached head commit

Tags: git

Suppose following scenario.

1. Create a branch in a local git repository on the master branch.
2. Checkout new branch and do some commits.
3. Checkout master branch again.
4. Delete the newly created branch.

Now, Is there a way to go back to the last commit I made in the newly created branch if I do not remember the commit id of it?

Comment: Use the reflog to refresh your memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a:

```sh
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

or if you use a recent version of git:

```sh
git checkout -
```